how to set up 3000+ lights for optimal rendering in cycles?
scence example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x46UKJVspdC2mhNL4XIPHGJJ-ap6FF9e/view?usp=sharing
Cycles: How can I minimize render time with a very large number of lights using only render settings and light settings? What light and render settings should I adjust other than reducing the output resolution and reducing the number of samples?
The max bounces value has almost no effect on render time


Perhaps with this number of lights it's better to have a single object with emissive material?

Why do you delete the question and ask it again? And this time again without any screenshot?

screenshot was not mine. I don't know who attached it and why. Deleted the question because of a comment about an incorrectly formed request. Now it seems rigth

Well, can you share a screenshot of the scene?

@Marius
https://i.ibb.co/0VqckfC/image.png

any user of the community with enough reputation can propose edits to a question or answer to enhance it, it's part of how the platform works. You can always refuse them, but the goal is always to make the best quality of Q&A. As an author, you are also expected to edit your own Q/A instead of deleting them to repost a duplicate. See the BSE Tour to get a quick overview of how the platform works, or the Help Centre to learn even more.

It's always tricky to render a massive amount of light objects in a ray-traced render. Too many variables to take into account for too little samples. The usual trick I know for this is to cut down your scene into different layers which you render individually, effectively dividing your light counts per layers, but your current instance system makes it a bit annoying to set up. Another one could be to bake your lights from the original non-instanced object into an image texture, and use that everywhere. It would be especially effective if it isn't animated.

To know on which solution to focus an answer, can you tell if that scene supposed to be animated and how?
